# How to convert string to use with Fernet in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, fernet

I want to convert a string to use it as a custom key for Fernet.

Current code

```
masterKey = base64.b64encode("F4D27D47".encode("utf-8"))
crypter = Fernet(masterKey)
```

However this raises and exception:

`ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message describes the problem exactly. Your key is neither 32 bytes (but only 8) nor is it Base64**url** encoded (but Base64). You can generate a 32 bytes Base64url encoded key e.g. with `key = Fernet.generate_key()`, see [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#fernet-symmetric-encryption). If you want to use a string/password, you can derive a 32 bytes key with a key derivation function (like PBKDF2), e.g. [here](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/fernet2).

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work fine:

```
code_bytes = code.encode("utf-8")
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(code_bytes.ljust(32)[:32])
fernet = Fernet(key)
```

ljust(32) pads the password bytes with null bytes to ensure the key is 32 bytes long. Then [:32] truncates the key to 32 bytes if it's longer than that. Finally, the key is encoded using base64.urlsafe_b64encode() to obtain a URL-safe base64-encoded key.